# How to loop through HTML elements and populate a Json-object?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I'm looping through all the html tags in an html-file, checking if those tags match conditions, and trying to compose a JSON-object of a following schema:

```
[
{    title: 'abc',    date: '10.10.10',    body: ' P tags here',    href: ''  },
{    title: 'abc',    date: '10.10.10',    body: ' P tags here',    href: ''  },
{    title: 'abc',    date: '10.10.10',    body: ' P tags here',    href: ''  }
]
```

But I'd like to create the new entry only for elements, classed "header", all the other elements have to be added to earlier created entry. How do I achieve that?

Current code:

```
$('*').each((index, element) => {


  if ( $(element).hasClass( "header" ) ) {
      jsonObject.push({
          title: $(element).text()
      });
  };
  if( $(element).hasClass( "date" )) {
      jsonObject.push({
          date: $(element).text()
      });
   }

   //links.push($(element))
});
console.log(jsonObject)
```

Result is:

```
  {
    title: 'TestA'
  },
  { date: '10.10.10' },
  {
    title: 'TestB'
  },
  { date: '10.10.11' }
```

I'd like it to be at this stage something like:

```
      {
        title: 'TestA'
      ,
       date: '10.10.10' },
      {
        title: 'TestB'
      ,
       date: '10.10.11' }
```

**UPD:**
Here's the example of HTML file:

```
<h1 class="header">H1_Header</h1>
<h2 class="date">Date</h2>
<p>A.</p>
<p>B.</p>
<p>С.</p>
<p>D.</p>
<a class="source"><a href="http://">http://</a></a>
<h1 class="header">H1_Header2</h1>
<h2 class="date">Date2</h2>
<p>A2.</p>
<p>B2.</p>
<p>С2.</p>
<p>D2.</p>
<a class="source"><a href="http://2">http://2</a></a>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How do you know which dates, etc. relate to the given header? Can you provide some sample `Html`?

Comment: The html code of the elements you are extracting the info from would be helpful here.

Comment: "How do you know which dates, etc. relate to the given header?"
That's a good question. Dates belong to the prior header. But the structure is flat. So if we ancounter a header - we create a new entry, for everything else we keep filling the previously created. That's how imagine, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example `Html`, it appears everything you are trying to collect is in a linear order, so you get a title, date, body and link then a new header with the associated items you want to collect, since this appears to not have the complication of having things being ordered in a non-linear fasion, you could do something like the following:

```
let jsonObject = null;
let newObject = false;
let appendParagraph = false;
let jObjects = [];

$('*').each((index, element) => {
  if ($(element).hasClass("header")) {
      //If newObject is true, push object into array
      if(newObject)
         jObjects.push(jsonObject);
      //Reset the json object variable to an empty object
      jsonObject = {};
      //Reset the paragraph append boolean
      appendParagraph  = false;
      //Set the header property
      jsonObject.header = $(element).text();
      //Set the boolean so on the next encounter of header tag the jsobObject is pushed into the array
      newObject = true;
  };

  if( $(element).hasClass( "date" )) {
      jsonObject.date = $(element).text();
  }

  if( $(element).prop("tagName") === "P") {
      //If you are storing paragraph as one string value
      //Otherwise switch the body var to an array and push instead of append
      if(!appendParagraph){ //Use boolean to know if this is the first p element of object
         jsonObject.body = $(element).text();
         appendParagraph = true; //Set boolean to true to append on next p and subsequent p elements
      } else {
         jsonObject.body += (", " + $(element).text()); //append to the body
      }

  }

  //Add the href property
  if( $(element).hasClass("source")) {
       //edit to do what you wanted here, based on your comment:
       jsonObject.link = $(element).next().html(); 
       //jsonObject.href= $(element).attr('href');
  }
});

//Push final object into array
jObjects.push(jsonObject);

console.log(jObjects);
```

Here is a jsfiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyojx85e/

I can't get the text of the anchor tags on the fiddle (I believe because nested anchor tags are not valid and will be parsed as seperate anchor tags by the browser), but the code provided should work in a real world example. If `.text()` doesn't work you can switch it to `.html()` on the link, I was confused on what you are trying to get on this one, so I updated the answer to get the href attribute of the link as it appears that is what you want. The thing is that the anchor with the class doesn't have an href attribute, so I'll leave it to you to fix that part for yourself, but this answer should give you what you need.

Comment: Works splendid! Huge thanks! And all the comments - helped to get what's going on.

To access link I've used .next() method. Thankfully cheerio supports most/all of them? of Jquery methods.

  `//Add the link property
          if($(element).hasClass("source")) {
              jsonObject.link = $(element).next().html();
          }
        });
`

Comment: @A.Howe Glad I could help you. Good to know you have a fix for the href portion. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').each((index, element) => {
  var obj = {};

  if ( $(element).hasClass( "header" ) ) {
    obj.title = $(element).text();
  };
  if( $(element).hasClass( "date" )) {
    obj.date = $(element).text()
   }

    jsonObject.push(obj);

});
```

Comment: if you would like there to always be date and title, you can add else{obj.title = null) and else obj.date = null.  So your objects have consistency

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response!

Unfortunately - it creates a new entry {} for every single tag, so tha total amount of entries is way bigger than desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery, but with JavaScript you can do with something like this.

```js
const arr = [];
document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((elem) => {
  const obj = {};
  const title = elem.querySelector("h2");
  const date = elem.querySelector("date");
  if (title) obj["title"] = title.textContent;
  if (date) obj["date"] = date.textContent;
  arr.push(obj);
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>A</h2>
    <date>1</date>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>B</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <date>3</date>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use map for things like this. This should look something like:

```
let objects = $('.header').get().map(el => {
  return {
    date: $(el).attr('date'),
    title: $(el).attr('title'),
  }
})
```

Comment: `"Always use map"`, that's a pretty finite answer with no reasons to back up that statement. Also, nothing about your answer would work with the OP's post as the `header` elements only contain the title not the date and you ommitted the paragraphs and hrefs.

Comment: [Use map instead of pushing things in an each](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators--nope) - the rest was just an example.